# save data for bookmark

Tags: android

I need some suggestion on the right approach to use for saving some bookmark data for my book-like android app I am making. Is using ShardPreference object the best way or what are other alternativs? I just need to save the page number and title in the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good tutorial on sqlite available here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

In my opinion this is the preferred way.

You could also create a file on the sd card where you save the data as strings manually. Although that will require your app to have the permission to access sd card contents:

https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card

Comment: WIll using SQLLite not be an overkill here given my data will be very small. I am just passing title, page number in the bookmark data and I don't see more than 20-25 entries saved as bookmark. Can I just not create a file under Assets whcih I read/write for updating the bookmark data?

Comment: I'd go with the SQLite db. It's small, fast and easy to use. As 323go suggested, the data access is pretty simple, you need not worry about how to exactl store the data.

Comment: Forgot to add something:

Although I have to admit that it looks a bit scary at first, here is another simple tutorial for the usage of SQLite :]

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite.html